# PowerShell scripting, Why does this fail to function? Where do I need to make improvements?

Tags: windows, events, powershell

The original issue was fixed, now there is a new issue. My cmd line isn't executing my ESE.exe file.
Lets see who can find a solution first.
Project website: https://sourceforge.net/projects/eventshredder/    -   This is an Open Source Project

```
$title = "Event Shredder"
$message = "Do you want to shred all the Event Viewer log files?"

$yes = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Yes", `
    ""

$no = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&No", `
    ""

$optionset = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($yes, $no)

$Form = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $optionset, 0) 

switch ($form)
    {
        0 {$CMD = 'C:\PowerShell\Program Files\Event Shredder\ESE.exe'}
        1 {}
        }

$title = "Register"
$message = "Would you like to register for free product updates?"

$yes = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Yes", `
    ""

$no = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&No", `
    ""

$optionset = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($yes, $no)

$form = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $optionset, 0) 

switch ($form)
    {
        0 {$IE=new-object -com internetexplorer.application
$IE.navigate2("https://sourceforge.net/projects/eventshredder/")
$IE.visible=$true}
        1 {$IE=new-object -com internetexplorer.application
$IE.navigate2("https://sourceforge.net/p/eventshredder/wiki/Home/")
$IE.visible=$true}
        }
```

Comment: put the code for the actions into your switch statements, $form1/2 contain the result of the dialog (0 = yes, 1=no). not sure what you are trying to accomplish with your if statements

Comment: I don't know what I was trying to do either. After you said that I took a serious look an thought to it and I knew something wasn't right about it the whole time I just couldn't put my finger on it.

Comment: Wow really? Why would somebody down vote this? If its helpful to me, it could be helpful to plenty of other people and just because YOU don't find it helpful doesn't mean you should down vote every question that doesn't help you that is just being selfish. Come on people, this isn't a popularity contest its an educational tool. We help each other out, is that not what this site is for because correct me if I am wrong but I will leave this site and go to superuser instead if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A quick web search turned [this](http://edgylogic.com/blog/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right/) up.

To run your command use:

```
$CMD = "C:\PowerShell\Program Files\Event Shredder\ESE.exe"
&$CMD
```

Comment: I can confirm this works, and it even does the process in the background and waits for it to complete before opening the next window. This was very helpful so thanks! (deserves up votes but I cannot because I am rank 1)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using this solution.

Since I was used to batch and CMD I trusted this to work but it failed
0 {$CMD = 'C:\PowerShell\Program Files\Event Shredder\ESE.exe'}

I replaced this with the following
0 {Start-Process 'C:\PowerShell\Program Files\Event Shredder\ESE.exe'}

Thanks to any of you who helped!